# MySQL "CASE WHEN" control VS multiple queries

Tags: mysql, performance, case-when

In between the 2 query cases below, which one is faster:

```
update t set v = case when id = 1000000 then 100 when id = 10000000 then 500 else v end
```

Or

```
update t set v = 100 where id = 1000000;
update t set v = 500 where id = 10000000;
```

the table t has an unique index on id and the table can be pretty big (millions of entry).

My guess is that although the second case make multiple queries it is still faster because it can use the index to find the entries while in the first case it is doing a full scan of the table (but it is just a guess, I have actually no clue on how MySQL deal with CASE control flow).

Thank you in advance for any answers !

Comment: Your first UPDATE is not equivalent to your second pair of UPDATES. Add a `where id in (1000000, 10000000)` to the first and benchmark them. And I think you mean to say `id = case when id = 1000000 then 100 when id = 10000000 then 500 end` in the first one.

Comment: @Mitch: explain doesn't work with update as far as I know.

Comment: MySQL 5.6.2 also now provides an EXPLAIN syntax for UPDATE and DELETE statements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: @mu: I want to set v to 100 for entry id 1000000 and v to 500 for entry id 10000000, what you suggest seems different.

Comment: @Mitch: I see, I didn't know that thanks a lot for the info. I should have precised I am using mysql 5.1... But if somebody with 5.6.2 could dump the explain plan, I would be very grateful...

Comment: Yes, they are quite different, mine is valid SQL and yours is not; mine also has a typo, it should be `v = case ...`, sorry about that. And once you fix the syntax error, you'll be putting NULLs in everthing where `id` is neither 1000000 nor 10000000, hence my suggesting about adding a WHERE clause.

Comment: @mu: thanks, I fixed the syntax by adding "when" tags.

Comment: @mu: I see, it set null if cases is not matching. That shows that "case" control do a full table scan and therefore is less efficient than multiple update isn't it ?

Comment: It shows that an UPDATE without a WHERE clause does a full table scan; if you don't tell MySQL which rows you want then it does them all. If you add a WHERE clause then your two cases will be equivalent and then you can start measuring performance.

Answer (score 0):

The second version you have would be better and cleaner, however, a cleaner single update is also possible to take advantage of the index on the "id" columns...

```
update t
   set v = if( id = 1000000, 100, 500 )
   where id in ( 1000000, 10000000 )
```

Comment: As other option you  can use " where id =1000000 or id=10000000". It is less complex to understand but will use index too.

Comment: @arheops, to me, and probably others too, using an IN, (as you say also utilizes the index) is easier and personal preference.  Now, as another 2, 3 or 4 other IDs to the list?  Which is easier to implement.

Comment: Thats vary. for 3 i still will do OR. for more i will try other methods. Just becuase people better understanding OR. SQL language itself was created to be human readable.